# *.Designer.vb not create custom property rightly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When you edit in Design Mode a control in VS, in designer.vb file changes happen, i.e: in a button, set width 200, height 100 as Size property, in designer.vs file of its form appears:

```
me.button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200,100) 'The standard constructor
```

I want to get the same with my custom class, but I only get:

```
me.custombutton.Situation.Tab = 0
me.custombutton.Situation.Row = 0
me.custombutton.Situation.Column = 0
```

instead of

```
me.custombutton.Situation = new Situation(0,0,0) 'As my constructor works.
```

Furthermore, I think this error generates null exception to init program...

My Custom Class:

```
 <TypeConverter(GetType(SituationConverter)), _
Description("Situation in a {tab, row, column} system"), _
Browsable(True), _
Serializable()> _
Public Class Situation
    Private _tab As Integer
    Private _row As Integer
    Private _column As Integer

    <DefaultValue(0), _
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property Tab As Integer
        Get
            Return _tab
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _tab = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue(0), _
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property Row As Integer
        Get
            Return _row
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _row = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue(0), _
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property Column As Integer
        Get
            Return _column
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _column = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(aTab As Integer, aRow As Integer, aColumn As Integer)
        Tab = aTab
        Row = aRow
        Column = aColumn
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SituationConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    ' tells the IDE what conversions it can handle:
    Public Overloads Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                              destType As Type) As Boolean
        If destType = GetType(Situation) Then
            ' Yes I Can
            Return True
        End If
        ' Probably have to also say YES to an InstanceDescriptor 
        Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destType)
    End Function


    Public Overloads Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                    culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                                    value As Object, destType As Type) As Object

        If destType = GetType(String) AndAlso TypeOf value Is Situation Then

            Dim sit As Situation = CType(value, Situation)
            Return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}",
                    sit.Tab.ToString,
                    sit.Row.ToString,
                    sit.Column.ToString)

            ' outputs: X, Y, <ex>
            ' where Ex is what we use in the ExtraItemConverter

        End If

        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destType)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function ConvertFrom(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                    culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                                    value As Object) As Object

        If TypeOf value Is String Then
            Try
                ' parse the string you made and create a Foo
                Dim els As String() = value.Split(","c)
                Return New Situation(Convert.ToInt32(els(0)), Convert.ToInt32(els(1)), Convert.ToInt32(els(2)))
            Catch
                Throw New ArgumentException("Can not convert '" & CStr(value) & _
                                            "' to type Situation")
            End Try
        End If



    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CanConvertFrom(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, sourceType As Type) As Boolean
        If sourceType = GetType(String) Then
            ' Yes I Can
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType)
    End Function

End Class
```

And in my custom button. the custom property:

```
       Dim _situation as New Situation(0,0,0) 'This resolved compile errors!!

    <Description("Situation in the {tab, row, column} system"),
           EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), _
   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
        Public Property Situation() As Situation
            Get
                Return _situation
            End Get
            Set(value As Situation)
                _situation = value
            End Set
        End Property

        'By answer of Visual Vincent
        Private Function ShouldSerializeSituation() As Boolean
            Return True
        End Function

        Private Sub ResetSituation()
            Dim s As Situation = New Situation(0, 0, 0)
            Situation = s
        End Sub
        '
```

Also, I set property value in Desgin mode as string i.e "1,2,1", but when compiling and running value set to nothing...

---

Edited:
I added code recommended by @Visual Vincent, and now get the following:

```
Me.btnCustom1.Situation.Column = 1
    Me.btnCustom1.Situation.Row = 1
    Me.btnCustom1.Situation.Tab = 0
```

But when running I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error ocurred creating the form.
>   See Exception.InnerException for details. ther error is: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.

It's should be related when my class....

Comment: The designer must be creating an instance of your control somewhere!

Comment: @MattWilko, designer already creates an instance of the control, but it doesn't initialice the property "Situation", simply add values to its properties "Tab", "Row" and "Column", when I think it needs do a call to constructor AKA new Situation(tab,row,column)

Comment: The `Size` object is a structure, and due to how it handles properties (because they're usually made immutable) you must initialize a new instance every time you want to change its values. Your `Situation` object is a class, which can not only change properties at any time, but it is also a reference type. This means that you usually only need to have one instance of it and modify that.

Comment: @VisualVincent ok, what you wrote has reason! But, why "Situation" values are reset when compiling and running the program? What have I to do for getting a persistent value of "Situation" property from Design editor?

Comment: Not sure about that, but as for your class's instance you would have to call that on your own. Due to that you've made a custom property and a field holding the `Situation` class, and since the class is no control, you must initialize it yourself in the button's constructor _**OR**_ declare your field like: `... _situation As New Situation(...)`

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you for the previous comment, it made me reflect. I simply changed form "class" to "structure" type for my "Situation" object, and it seems to be it works fine at least with .designer file. If you want, write this advice as answer and I'll validate it as good answer ;)

Comment: ... but when I compile or clean my project values set to default again :(

Comment: I think that might be due to the parameterless `Public Sub New()` constructor. If you're not using it, try removing it and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: You cannot convince the designer to use your constructor, it has no idea that it does the right thing with your properties.  Unless you write a custom code serializer for the class, ugh factor applies.  The solution is very simple, apply the `<Serializable>` attribute to your Situation class.  Now the designer can simply store the value in the form's .resx file.  The [DefaultValue] attribute doesn't work either, write a private Sub ShouldSerializeSituation() As Boolean function in your control class.  And you ought to write a ResetSituation() method.

Comment: @Hans Passant the first part about <Serializable> was clear, but the the second part wasn't for me. In my ButtonCustom control, where I put "Situation" property, what should I add? Could you provide an brief explanation or a sample link? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no real idea what is unclear about it.  Just write the method (oops, Function and not Sub) and return False if any of the Situation property members is not 0.  Sub ResetSitutation() should set them to 0.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your help, but I have no idea how to write a function called ShouldSerializeSituation() (what gets a boolean with true value I think) and write a sub ResetSituation() in the ButtonCustom class could help to store its values in form.designer.vb file...

Comment: If you want to use your ctor overload, you need to also handle `InstanceDescriptor` in the Typeconverter to provide that code.  One by one should work as well though since the default appears to be 0 for them all.  Not sure about the NRE. not enough info given

Comment: I think all of this escapes of my current .NET knowledge, I only followed a Microsoft Tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx which I see easy to adapt to my problem. I just want to edit custom properties in a custom control from Design editor

Comment: Oh, I am quite certain you consulted/borrowed from sources other than just MSDN. I cant work out what problem you are trying to solve. The question seems to be something other than what is in comments. I tweaked a few things - mostly removing superfluous code and it works fine

Comment: @mzurita : Have you tried: `Public Function ShouldSerializeSituation() As Boolean`?

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, I added to my code. But I got an error when running the program. I updated the question.

Comment: Don't show the `MyApplication` code, it just breaks there because it occurs when the form loads/is about to load. Show the declaration of the function that I wrote instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent corrected. I added a initialization value to Situation property of my custom control solved the problem. Now, with your help the designer file store the value of the properties and program works fine ;)

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck in the future!